# English translation of two papers by Polya on real zeros of Fourier transform approximation to Riemann $\xi$ function

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-zeta

I am looking for English translation of the following two papers by Polya:

[1] G. Polya, Bemerkung über die Integraldarstellung der Riemannschen $\xi$-Funktion,
Acta Math. 48(1926), 305-317; reprinted in his Collected Papers, Vol. II, pp. 243–255.

[2] G. Polya, Über trigonometrische Integrale mit nur reellen Nullstellen, 
J. Reine Angew. Math. 158(1927), 6-18; reprinted in his Collected Papers, Vol. II, pp. 265–275.

Thanks a lot for the heads-up!
Mike

Comment: not sure you need translation, most of maths german papers nearly are only math formulas, they know that people won't read german parts, so they resctrict them to the minimum of the minimum

Comment: @reuns Thanks for the encouragement. I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no English translations available for these papers. The first one, i.e., *Bemerkung über die Integraldarstellung der Riemannschen ξ-Funktion*, is shortly discussed in English here by M. Kac:

http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/polya.htm

Answer (score 1):

My translation of [1] can be found [here](https://latexonline.cc/compile?git=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fthosgood%2Ftranslations&target=am-48%2Fintegral-representation-xi-function.tex&command=pdflatex&trackId=1602775014854) (or at https://thosgood.com/translations/ if the above link ever breaks).